# Not able to install VI editor/vim in docker container

Tags: windows, docker, vim, apache-pulsar

Hello everyone,

I am trying to install vim in my docker pulsar(I pulled the pulsar image in my docker container) container, I have docker in my windows machine.
I used two commands
                       Both commands is failing.....

first: apt-get update

```
Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  
Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch- 
updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian- 
security/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease  Could not resolve ' 
'security.debian.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones 
used instead.
```

second: apt-get install vim

```
libgpm2 vim vim-common vim-runtime xxd
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 6766 kB of archives.
After this operation, 31.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 xxd amd64 2:8.0.0197- 
4+deb9u1
Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 vim-common all 
2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u1
Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 libgpm2 amd64 1.20.4- 
6.2+b1
Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 vim-runtime all 
2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u1
Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 vim amd64 2:8.0.0197- 
4+deb9u1
Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch 
http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/vim/xxd_8.0.0197-4+deb9u1_amd64.deb  
Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/vim/vim- 
common_8.0.0197-4+deb9u1_all.deb  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch 
http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gpm/libgpm2_1.20.4-6.2+b1_amd64.deb  
Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/vim/vim- 
runtime_8.0.0197-4+deb9u1_all.deb  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
E: Failed to fetch 
http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/vim/vim_8.0.0197-4+deb9u1_amd64.deb  
Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with -- 
fix-missing?
```

I am attaching screen shot as well.
What would be the reason ?[image: error in vim installation]

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with your DNS. I am sure that if you do:

```
$ ping deb.debian.org
```

You will also get an error.

I would recommend you to read [this](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/)